# Deploying Angular2 on WebLogic 12c

Tags: angular2-services

I am a beginner to angular-2 and tested a small project on nodejs server - used Webclipse IDE.

How do I deploy angular-2 project on WebLogic 12c ?

Comment: Is it a pure Angular App or has some server side code too? Trying to deploy through IDE or external deployment?

Comment: This is not pure angular app - only the UI part is done in a J2EE compliant app. We do deployment using uDeploy and other tools.